# Nginx server responds to ip but not domain name

Tags: nginx

I have a server with nginx setup. I want it to respond to the domain `testhero.in.th`.

So in the config file, in my server block, I set `server_name testhero.in.th`.

I try to access the site through the domain and I get **server took too long to respond**. So I use dig to see if the domain is pointing to my server. I get an A record pointing to my server. The ip is `188.166.198.107`.

I then enter the ip into the address bar and I can then access the site.

To make sure, I tail the access log for nginx. When I try to access the server using the ip, I see the logs, but when I try to access through the domain, I don't.

What steps should I take to find out why I can't access the site through my domain name?

Comment: Works for me here. Check your hosts file

Comment: Was not working for me, cleaned my browser cache and then it worked. Don't know why that matters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best bet is that your client is not contacting the server.
The steps are the following :

- double check that there is no dns problem (ie that when you ping testhero.in.th, 
  the IP cobntacted by your client is 188.166.198.107
- check that your browser is not using a proxy for testhero.in.th ( maybe your browser is configured to use a proxy, but has a list of exception that includes the ip of the server).
- clean your browser cache.
- try another browser. wget and curl are good bet.

If everything fails, your can still use tcpdump server side to check if there are incoming connections for your client IP

Comment: I cleaned my browser cache and it started working. Do you know why that matters? Another issue I encountered when I tried redirecting to https version of the site but then again, it wouldn't respond. Turns out firewall was blocking port 443. All good now.

Comment: No idea. I edited the answer accoring to your comment in case it helps someone else. The problem was actually client side.

Comment: Perhaps the browser had the DNS response cached from previous attempts when the name was still pointing to a different IP address? Clearing the cache then fixes the issue.